# CS50 pset3 tideman print_winner

Tags: cs50

thanks to all of you. I am finally finished with my problem set 3 tideman. However, there is still one thing bugged me.

In the last function, we have to print out the winner (the candidate with no edge locked onto/ the source).
[image]

You see in the picture above, clearly, 2 is the winner.
I have searched for many answers on the internet, they all just test out if 2 has been locked onto by others. But they did not test if 2 has locked onto other candidates or not.

Consider the below example.

Candidate: A, B, C

No. of Voters: 2

Voter1:

Rank1-3: A -> B -> C

Voter2:

Rank1-3: C -> B -> A

The graph will pretty much look like this:
[image]

This is a tie where no candidate is prefered over the others.
But the tideman programme will still print A as the winner, as A has not been locked on by any other candidates.

Do we need to consider tie situation in this problem? Or am i missing something here? Please help me out.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The specification says: "You may assume there will not be more than one source".
So, for the CS50 problem set, we can assume the situation you described would never occur.
But your reasoning is right. Ties can occur.